# Can't send 2 SMS at a time

Tags: ios, swift, sms, presentviewcontroller

using xcode swift, I am trying to send several SMS to different persons in one loop. I used a "for X in Y", I checked and it is reading all the X, but I have only the first SMS sent, the others are not sent. I did not manage to wait until the fist SMS is sent to go to the next one.

Below my code:

```
for recette in Recettes {
    var messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    messageVC.body = "Pour demain: \(recette.Sujet)";
    messageVC.recipients = [recette.Number]
    messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: What made you think you could put presentViewController in a loop? You need to read up on the fundamentals

Comment: ok, good to know. I am quite new in programming, so I am happy to take any advice or reference to useful documentation.